# Read the row in the JSON only if the array for media is NOT EMPTY

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, get

I would like to read the row in the JSON only if the array for media is NOT EMPTY.

However the code below does not work. Although I have defined

- ( data.rows[j].media.length >=1 ) or
- ( data.rows[j].media != undefined )

It will still read the the array for media which is EMPTY.
.

```
// JSON data

{
  author: "Mary",  
  media: [ ],
},
{
  author: "Nelson",  
  media: [ 
   {
      type: "Image", 
      link: "https://...jpeg"
   }
  ]
}
// Jquery to get the data from JSON

$.ajax('https://rest.xyz.com/', {
type: 'GET', 
dataType: 'json',
success: function( data ) {  
  var m = 0;
  for(j in data.rows){
     if ( data.rows[j].media.length >=1 ) { 
       if (data.rows[j].media[0].type == 'Video'){ }
       else {  } 
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: If im not mistakes length does work when referring to a json object.  Try `data.rows[j].media[0] !=null` instead of `data.rows[j].media.length >=1`.

Comment: I tried the above two method as you have suggested but it has TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.rows[j].media[0].type')

Answer (score 1):

Try

*data.rows[j].media.ToString()!= "[]"*

or

*data.rows[j].media.ToString()!= "[ ]"*